# Why duplicate posts are not closed

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are many changes came to Stack Overflow; I could see one of it.

- **Before:** Duplicate posts were closed, when those were flagged.
- **Now:** Duplicate posts are not closed.

What is the reason behind this?

[Example: Closed post as it is duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5591431/668970).

[This one of post which i flagged as duplicate and mod commented as "helpful" but not closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9781170/668970). Also there are 3 to 4 post which I flagged and got approved by mods but not closed

Comment: Do you have any links to duplicates that aren't closed?

Comment: Please check the update ChrisF. Mention reason for down voting please

Comment: I didn't down-vote.

Comment: @Damodar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9781170/668970) is only 6 hours old (as of this writing) and <strike>now has 4 close votes</strike> is now closed.

I suspect that the moderator looked at the age of the question and decided that while it is, in all probability a duplicate, the normal process of community votes would be sufficient for the question to get closed in a reasonable time.

Flags should only really be used in cases where the community can't act. In the case of unclosed duplicates it would be when the question is quite old (> 60 days, say) and is therefore unlikely to get the views that will get converted into close votes.

Comment: ChrisF : iam not getting, why people are downvoting without reason behind, is this not worthy question

Comment: ChrisF : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9764601/668970 this one too waiting for close, please check once...